# hibernate throws propertyValueException when persisting java entity model

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

First my apology. I can't state the question well/clearly enough.

I have a web application built upon jsf 2.x + spring data jpa + hibernate frameworks. There is an editable dataTable in where you could add/remove/update a row. When you click "Add Row" button new instance of car object (entity domain model) is added to a list then when you press save button, it is persisted to database just fine. Very straight forward.

This is foo.xhtml page.

```
<p:panelGrid>
  <p:row>
     <p:column>....</p:column>
  <p:column>
    <h:form id="fooForm">
      <p:dataTable id="fooTable" var="c" value="#{fooBean.cars}" 
        editable="true" rows="10" paginator="true">
        ......
            <f:facet name="footer">
              <p:commandButton value="Add Row" actionListener="#{fooBean.addCar}" 
                     update="fooTable" process="@this" />                               
            </f:facet>
       </p:dataTable>
       <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{fooBean.save}" update="fooTable" process="@this"/>                                               
    </h:form>   
   </p:column>
  </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

This is bean.

```
@ManaagedBean
@Viewscoped
public FooBean class implements Serializable {
    .....
    public void addCar() {
         ....
    }

    public void save() {
    // use spring abstraction layer to persist entity object
    }
```

> Issue I ran into:

However the trouble I am having is once I decided to remove "Save" button from foo.xhtml and

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{fooBean.save}" .../>
```

move save() method inside of addCar() method from the FooBean

```
public void addCar() {
    ....
    save();
}
```

The following exception is thrown when I click "Add Row" button and I've been trying to understand why but failed so far.

```
SEVERE: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient valu
e: com.yoon.model.Car.age; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not
-null property references a null or transient value: com.yoon.model.Car.age
```

> Update with self explanatory answer

It turns out to be a programmatic error of mine. When I click on "Add Row" from a table, it should handle only adding an instance of car model with its fields fully entered and add the object to a list. However when I relocated save method inside of addCar method that gets triggered by clicking "Add Row" button, empty car object in where fields are all NULL pushed by hibernate to DB before it grants a chance a user to fill out the required fields. In the table, those fields CAN NOT BE NULLABLE so in turn aforementioned exception was thrown.

I was able to achieve my initial objective of clicking "Add Row" button would capture user input and persist an instance of car to database.

Removing following button

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{fooBean.save}" />
```

Having ajax component.

```
<p:dataTable ....>
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{fooBean.save}" />
....
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Can you share `Car` entity, because it's complaining about the field `age` being set to NULL when it shouldn't.

Comment: This is not a JSF problem. You'd better retag the question and remove the JSF related stuff.

Comment: @Tiny: Thanks for your suggestion. You may be right however I have to stress that when I remove PF commandButton executes "Save" method then entity model's fields come out as null. Not the entity model, car itself. If I keep that button as it is described in this thread then car's fields are correctly captured.Nothing changed except the PF button and relocation of the method. It is hard to shake off it has nothing to do with JSF.

Comment: @Luay Abdulraheem: yes, you are right. The age field/column data can't null in entity mdoel. (nullable=false). I updated my question but if I relocate "fooBean.save" inside of "fooBean.addCar". The entity model (car) is not null but all the fields coming out as null. I don't think it has anything to do with structure of entity model though b/c if I keep "addCar" and "save" separately then car instance is correctly persisted to DB.

Comment: @Tiny@Luay Abdularheem: It has nothing to do with JSF. As I comb through inside save method. I found an error in the logic. Thank you for your advice. Have a blessed day!

Comment: I added Update with self explanatory answer of what caused the error.